# Disproving completeness of an HPC-like proof system

Tags: logic, hilbert-calculus

**Question**

Given a new proof system S which contains the following axioms:

The regular HPC axioms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system) P1-P4.

A new axiom is introduced: $(a \lor b) \rightarrow (\lnot a \rightarrow b)$

The deduction rules are:
Modus Ponens and the following rules: $\frac a{a \lor b}, \frac b{a \lor b}$

Prove that S is not complete over sentences with the operators $\rightarrow , \lnot, \lor$.

It's given that this system is sound.

**Proof idea**

I've been told that I need to assume that $\vdash_S p \lor \lnot p$ and somehow get a contradiction from it , but I just can't see the formal way to prove this, I would love some explanation of the formal way to disprove completeness of such systems.
Thanks in advance.